# Applying Cantor's Theorem to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's Theorem tells us that the cardinality of the powerset of a set $S$ is strictly greater than the cardinality of $S$ itself. Cantor's proof of this is wonderful--as short as it is clever.

After offering the proof, the introductory real analysis book I have follows up with a corollary: $$|\Bbb N|< |\mathcal P (\Bbb N)|< |\mathcal P(\mathcal P (\Bbb N))|, \mathrm {etc.}$$

And this makes sense; it's just a straighforward application of the theorem to $\Bbb N$. But how do we know that Cantor's Theorem applies to countably infinite sets just like it does to finite ones?

Granted, the theorem doesn't assume anything that would preclude its application to $\Bbb N$ (or other countably infinite sets), and granted we're using a method of counting that can be applied as readily to infinite sets as finite ones. Allowing all of that, it still seems hasty to me that the theorem would be at once applied to $\Bbb N$.

I seem to be thinking that some additional requirement is needed before applying the result of the theorem to an infinite set. But clearly no such additional requirement is needed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you should first answer this question: what motivation is there to think that Cantor's Theorem wouldn't work for 'big sets'?

Comment: I've thought about that: What's the concern? What could possibly go wrong with the theorem when applying it to infinite sets? And I think, "Nothing could go wrong."

Comment: You're right. So the problem is...?

Comment: But still the doubt is still there. Is there really nothing else needed? Am I really supposed to accept at one that the theorem can be applied to N?

Comment: @Ryan: Maybe it would help if you quoted the proof you use and highlighted the steps which you have doubts about.

Comment: @Ryan I can't understand what you don't get, sorry. If you accept the proof of Cantor's Theorem, you have to accept that it can be applied to $\Bbb N$ and to $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. Do you understand the proof?

Comment: Perhaps I just need to allow it to sink in. Maybe it's just a matter of the theorem being counterintuitive (infinitely many cardinalities, all greater than N?!) and unfamiliar.

Comment: I do understand the proof--it's wonderful.

Comment: Purdy indeed. ${}$

Comment: Thanks for taking a moment to talk this out with me. I'm learning this material on my own, and I don't have anyone to turn to and say, "Really!?"

Comment: One of the reasons mathematics relies so heavily on proofs, rather than other sorts of evidence, and why mathematicians insist on keeping careful track of hypotheses, is that, once a theorem is proved, it is guaranteed to be true in *every* situation where its hypotheses are satisfied, whether or not the person proving the theorem or someone else reading the proof ever though of that situation. In the case at hand, once Cantor's theorem is proved without any hypothesis of finiteness, it's guaranteed to be true, even for infinite sets.

Comment: @Ryan I've provided a proof below; if you read it and have any doubts about any particular step, then please let me know and we can discuss it.

Comment: @Ryan: I think the perplexing part, really, is the very existence of infinite sets. Note that there are not only infinitely many cardinalities, but unboundedly many: for any set $X$, you can find a family of sets with distinct cardinalities that is larger than $X$, at least assuming choice.

Comment: It was for the purpose of applying the argument to infinite sets that Cantor wrote the argument.  Nobody would have thought such an argument was needed for finite sets.

Answer (score 7):

Cantor's theorem (along with its usual proof) is valid for *every* set, finite or not. (For finite sets, the result is almost trivial anyway.)

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as calling the result trivial for finite sets. It requires rigorous proof that $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^{|X|}$ for a finite set $X$. And these proofs are often hard, exactly because we don't know what there is to prove.

Comment: Hi @Asaf, the weaker result that simply $\left|X\right|<\left|{\cal P}(X)\right|$ is trivial (or, at least, comparatively trivial compared to the general case) for finite sets, I think.

Comment: @Amitesh: I disagree. Having TA'd an intro course to set theory for three years, and proving both the finite case (by induction) and the general case later on, I can tell you that the finite case is not very trivial for those who actually need it in the first place.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: I agree that it's trivial to show that if $X$ has $n$ elements, then $n+1\leq\lvert \mathcal P(X)\rvert$. But to show that $n<n+1$ in the sense that there is no injection from $n+1$ into $n$ (or no surjection in the other direction), while very basic, I wouldn't call trivial. At least not to someone who has little to no experience with inductive proofs.

Comment: Note that I said *almost* trivial. The question was tagged real-analysis when I answered it, and in that context, $n < n+1$ hardly requires a proof that there is no injection from $n+1$ to $n$. In the context of set theory I agree that it does.

Comment: @Asaf I agree that it isn't trivial for students learning this topic for the first time. (In fact, very little is trivial for many students learning a topic for the first time.)

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a set, then there is an injection $\phi:A\to {\cal P}(A)$ given by $a\to \{a\}$. Therefore, $\left|A\right|\leq \left|{\cal P}(A)\right|$. However, let $\psi:A\to {\cal P}(A)$ be a function and define $X=\{a\in A:a\not\in \psi(a)\}$.

***Exercise***: Prove that $X\in {\cal P}(A)$ cannot be in the image of $\psi:A\to {\cal P}(A)$. We conclude that $\psi:A\to {\cal P}(A)$ is not surjective. (*Hint*: use proof by contradiction.)

Therefore, $\left|A\right|<\left|{\cal P}(A)\right|$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think the proof is *slightly* more constructive if you instead say that any function $A\to \mathcal P(A)$ is not surjective. I believe in replacing proofs by contradiction by direct ones whenever it doesn't make them much more convoluted, and especially when it makes them actually simpler. Of course, the indirect method is still used later, but at least you avoid nesting them. Nesting proofs by contradiction can sometimes be very misleading, as it's easy to forget which assumptions (and their consequences!) are material, and which are merely part of the reductio ad absurdum argument.

Comment: @tomasz Great point! In fact, I agree with you and have edited my answer.